# How do I create a fixed size text box within a div? Image attached

Tags: css, textbox

The input text ("ooooooo's") you can see is continuing across the complete page and under the images. I would like it to stop inside the the area shaded red. How would I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: can you post some code so it will be easy to look into this btw did u try setting the z-index? and also the red bar and the rest is one single image?

Comment: Can you just try setting the width of #user-info-box to the width of the red highlighted area? Probably still need more info.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried setting the "100%" to 250px and the text writes right through it as before.  Here's the php code           <td>
                 
                  <textarea name="bio-info" rows="3"  maxlength="120" class="left-fields-table-data-fields"> <?php echo $finalbioinfo; ?></textarea>
                 
                  </td>

Answer (score 1):

You can give any element a fixed width using the CSS width attribute. This will work whether you're allowing input text or just displaying text.

Examples:

```
div{
width:400px;
background-image:url("yourimage.png");
}

textarea{
width:400px;
background-image:url("yourimage.png");
}
```

Your text should be inside that element. If you're having problems with long words (like your example with the ooooooooo) you can set `word-wrap: break-word`

Comment: Thank you...I discovered that long "words" (I was counting the number of characters) without spaces broke the box.

Comment: Glad I could assist. Feel free to set my solution to the accepted answer or upvote if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `overflow: hidden` in your CSS. Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) for more info.

Comment: I would like the text to stop and start a second line inside the text box. (I'm looking for exactly what these forum reply text boxes do.)                                                            #user-info-box {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 50px;
border-bottom: solid 1px black;
text-align: center;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-ser

Answer (score 0):

Use a textarea for this element. It's built-in behavior is what you are looking for. You can style it with CSS to fit your layout.

I also suggest you get the Firebug plug-in for Firefox. When you see something you like on the web, it will allow you to right-click and see the html, JavaScript, css, etc., (anything client-side) in a box at the bottom of your browser. You can even edit the code and see the results of your experiments in real time. It is invaluable for those "just like so-and-so does it" situations.